# If $0\leq A\leq B$ then the corresponding densities satisfy $0\leq\rho_A\leq \rho_B$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $A,B$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb C^d)$ such that $0\leq A\leq B$ AND $A,B$ are trace-class. Then their densities are given by $$\rho_A(x):=\sum_jA\varphi_j(x)\overline{\varphi_j(x)},\qquad \rho_A(x):=\sum_jB\varphi_j(x)\overline{\varphi_j(x)},$$where $(\varphi_j)$ is an orthonormal basis on $L^2(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb C^d)$. Equivalently, $\rho_A(x)=K_A(x,x)$ where $K_A=K_A(x,y)$ is the integral kernel of $A$ (and similarly for $B$). I am trying to prove the relation $0\leq \rho_A\leq \rho_B$.

Not sure where to start with this one.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Just general operators? Then the densities could be not well-defined

Comment: Will edit now, oops!

Comment: @LL3.14 Does it work with the additional assumption that $A,B$ are trace-class?

Answer (score 2):

Attempted sketch of proof, please check carefully.

Consider $A, B$ trace-class. They can be represented as an integral Hilbert-Schmidt operator
$$ A f : x \mapsto \int K_A(x,y) f(y) dy \qquad , \qquad B f : x \mapsto \int K_B(x,y) f(y) dy $$
with $K_A$ and $K_B$ unique up to a.s. equality. For every measurable set $C\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, writing $[C]$ for the indicator function of $C$, using $\cdot$ for the pointwise multiplication of function,
$$ A_C : f \mapsto [C] \cdot A (f \cdot [C]) = \left( x \mapsto \int [C](x) K_A(x,y) [C](y) f(y) dy \right) $$
is trace-class with kernel $(x,y) \mapsto [C](x) [C](y) K_A(x,y)$. Note that for every $f\in L^2(C, \mathbb C^d)$, $A_C f = [C] \cdot A f$.

We check that $\mathrm{Tr}(A_C) \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A)$: to see this, define an orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ of $L^2(C, \mathbb C^d)$ and complete it with $(f_j)_{j\in J}$ to an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C^d)$, then write
$$ \mathrm{Tr}(A_C) = \sum_{i\in I} \langle e_i, A_C e_i \rangle = \sum_{i\in I} \langle e_i, A e_i \rangle \leq \sum_{i\in I} \langle e_i, A e_i \rangle + \sum_{j\in J} \langle f_j, A f_j \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A) . $$
Similarly with $B$, and using that $0\leq \langle e_i, A e_i\rangle \leq \langle e_i, B e_i \rangle$, we get $0 \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A_C) \leq\mathrm{Tr}(B_C)$.
We can also express the trace from the kernels:
$$ 0 \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A_C) = \int [C](x) K_A(x,x) [C](x) dx = \int_C K_A(x,x) dx \leq \int_C K_B(x,x) dx . $$
This holds for every $C$ measurable. Take $C = \{ x : K_A(x,x) > K_B(x,x) \}$: necessarily $C$ has Lebesgue measure zero, meaning $K_A(x,x) \leq K_B(x,x) $ for Lebesgue-almost all $x\in \mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Nice answer. Just wondered about the justification of finding an orthonormal basis of $L^2(C,\mathbb C^d)$ for every measurable set $C$?

Comment: $L^2(C,\mathbb C^d)$ is a Hilbert space, and thus admits a basis that is orthonormal with respect to its inner product $\langle f,g\rangle_C = \int_C \bar f g$.

As a side-note, since $L^2(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C^d) = L^2(C, \mathbb C^d) \oplus L^2(\mathbb R^d \setminus C, \mathbb C^d)$ where the two spaces are orthogonal, we can (and should) take $(f_j)$ as an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb R^d \setminus C, \mathbb C^d)$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Also, is it necessary that $B$ is trace-class? Would it work if only $A$ is trace class?